# Can I use Prompts from SLDS in my managed app?

Tags: slds

While reading through the docs about [Promts](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/guidelines/messaging/components/prompts/), I noticed this guideline:

> Note: If you’re a partner building an app that appears within
>   Salesforce, don’t use this component.

Does it imply that I should not use this type of messaging in my managed package. If yes, then why? I really need such behavior in my app, so when a user clicks on a list view custom action button, I'd like to show a prompt if there are some system errors, e.g. the app couldn't load a list of records required for the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prompts are meant for system messages, and [Modals](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/guidelines/messaging/components/modals/) are meant for non-system messages. This distinction helps users visually identify messages that come from Salesforce versus those that are custom. It is recommended that blocking dialogs are kept to a minimum, since they interrupt the user's interaction with Salesforce, but should certainly be used when the situation calls for it. Note that the sentence you've quoted is not meant to discourage developers from using blocking dialogs, but simply meant to reserve *this specific dialog* for Salesforce-generated messages. It helps provide a visual style that is distinct from other messages so users can identify them as system messages.